# MonoDroid Fails to load emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, xamarin.android

I downloaded the trail version of MonoDroid. I am going through the hello world tutorial and now at the part where I want to deploy my app to the emulator.

It comes up with a "Select Device" dialog with nothing in it. So I click on "Start emulator image", this pops up another dialog with available images. I have one emulator made and it is in this dialog box. I hit ok and I am not at dialog box with still nothing to choose.

So I am not sure what to do.

I am running Visual Studios pro 2010 on a window 7 64bit.

Comment: Did you also download and install the android-sdk?  Can you start an emulator outside of Visual Studio?

Comment: @antlersoft - Yep I have the android-sdk. I made a hello world application in eclipse and ran it through the emulator(it is slow but it runs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a regression in Google's latest version of the Android SDK. Emulators will no longer run if there are spaces in SDK location path.

Uninstall the Android SDK and install it back to a new location without spaces and it should work.

Comment: ya this seems to make it popup the emulator now. But the emulator is so slow(I have not timed it but it feels like forever). It just sits on the screen with the android logo. I don't think this has anything to do with monodroid as I tried it through eclipse, monodroaid, toolkit. All same slow. I tried to use the snapshop thing but nothing helps. Was about to just post a new post about this. So far not impressed with android.